# Showing animation to call function in android

Tags: android

Is it possible to show any animation when I call a function in same class in android?

In my application, I called a function "doAddition" so many times. And I want whenever I call this function, it shows some animation.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the classes in [`android.view.animation`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/package-summary.html) will be useful.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you looking for is the [ProgressBar](http://mobiforge.com/designing/story/understanding-user-interface-android-part-2-views).

Answer (score 0):

[ProgressDialog](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html) would be a quick solution as well.